# WPF: get application usage memory

Tags: c#

I want to get `application` usage memory so iam using this code:

```
Process applicationProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
int nProcessID = applicationProcess.Id;
long memoryUsed = applicationProcess.WorkingSet64;
string mem = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(memoryUsed).ToString();

private double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}
```

And the problem is that according `Windows task Manager` my `application` memory  usage is `~50MB` and according this code is `~130MB` (i also compare the `process` id)

Not even close.
Any idea what can cause this gap ?

Comment: Windows Task Manager [does not show memory in use by managed processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx). You have to use a memory profiler to determine this.

Comment: did you checked your code memory in Visual studio Diagnostic Tool ?

Comment: no, this should be different ?

Comment: And also what is the correct memory usage? The one from Task manager or the one I get from my code?